# add this share to Facebook not sharing image

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share, addthis

I'm using the addthis toolbox to share pages on my site to social media. This is my entire addthis section:

```
<div class="print_share">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <!-- addthis print button begin -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
                <a class="addthis_button_print"><svg class="icon icon--print"><use xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/icons/svg-sprite.svg#icon-print"></use></svg> Print</a>
            </div>
            <!-- addthis print button end-->            
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- addthis email button begin -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
                <a class="addthis_button_email"><svg class="icon icon--email"><use xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/icons/svg-sprite.svg#icon-email"></use></svg> Email</a>
            </div>
            <!-- addthis email button end-->            
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- addthis menu button begin -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" data-media="http://i.imgur.com/sI5mrZP.png">
                <div class="share_interstitial" style="display: none">
                    <span class="at16nc at300bs at15nc at15t_compact at16t_compact"><span class="at_a11y">More Sharing Services</span></span>
                    <a>Share</a>
                    <div class="share_loading" style="display: none"><img height="50" src="/images/loading.gif"/><span>Generating thumbnail image...</span></div>
                </div>
                <a class="addthis_button_compact"><svg class="icon icon--share"><use xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/icons/svg-sprite.svg#icon-share"></use></svg> Share</a>
            </div>
            <!-- addthis menu button end-->
        </li>
        <li><span>Hello</span></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I also have this script, which I added the `$(document).ready()` method to:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_share = {
        url_transforms: {
            shorten: {
                twitter: 'bitly'
            }
        },
        shorteners: {
            bitly: {}
        },
        media: "http://i.imgur.com/sI5mrZP.png"
    };

    var addthis_config = {
        ui_click: true,
        services_compact: 'facebook,twitter,more',
        services_exclude: 'gmail,email,print,printfriendly,favorites,blogger,w3validator'

    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(addthis);
        if (typeof addthis !== 'undefined') {
            addthis.update('share', 'image', "http://i.imgur.com/sI5mrZP.png");
            if (addthis_share.passthrough) {
                addthis_share.passthrough.pinterest_share.media = "http://i.imgur.com/sI5mrZP.png";
            }
            addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox', addthis_config, addthis_share);
        }
    });

</script>
```

but the image is never getting included. Why is it not sharing the image when I have the property `data-media` set on the `addthis_toolbox` element?

Comment: Put og:image tag on the URL that you are sharing.

Comment: I added `<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/sI5mrZP.png">` to the page but it's still not sharing that image

Comment: Then use Facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ .